# identifier not found with included class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include, identifier, undefined-reference

I have the following "comuni.cpp" file

```
#pragma once
#include "afxwin.h"

class Esame: public CObject
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(Esame)

public:
    INT voto;
    INT crediti;
    BOOL lode;
    CString nome;
    Esame(CString nome, INT voto, BOOL lode, INT crediti) :nome(nome), voto(voto), lode(lode), crediti(crediti) {}
    Esame(){  }
    void Serialize(CArchive &ar)
    {
        CObject::Serialize(ar);
        if (ar.IsStoring())
            ar << nome << "\n" << voto << "\n" << lode << "\n" << crediti << "\n";
        else
            ar >> nome  >> voto >> lode >> crediti;
    }

};
IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(Esame, CObject, 1)


class GestoreId {
private:
    static UINT id;
public:
    static UINT dammi_id()
    {
        id++;
        return id;
    }
};
UINT GestoreId::id;
```

if I include this file from another with

```
#include "comuni.cpp"
```

the other file see just Esame Class, but GestoreId give me identifier not found error! why?
Obviusly, all the references to GestoreId are after include directive ( then after its declaration and definition). If I cut and copy GestoriId definition in the caller file it works!

Comment: why exactly are you including a `*.cpp` file? and what is `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL`?

Comment: it's just for test. IMPLEMENT_SERIAL is used to serialize Esame class

Comment: Please include the _exact_ error text in your question.

Comment: This: `UINT GestoreId::id;` has no business being in a multi-included file (which is *terribly* named if is a .cpp file). And unrelated, `dammi_id` can simply be `return ++id;`

Comment: I already trying to put UINT GestoreId::id; in the other file but it's the same; the exact error is GestoreId is not the name of a class or of a namespace